# Returned "Access to model denied." from Google AI Platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I made a Tensorflow model and uploaded files to GCP storage.

I tried to get prediction results from Google AI Platform. But it showed errors.

I made a serviceAccount for model 'vgg_16' with below roles.

```
roles/iam.securityAdmin
roles/iam.securityReviewer
roles/ml.admin
roles/ml.developer
roles/ml.modelOwner
roles/ml.modelUser
roles/ml.viewer
roles/owner
roles/viewer
```

also, billing is activated for my project.

My codes:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import numpy
import base64
import logging
from IPython.display import display, Image

from google.cloud import storage

cropped_image = "8-android.widget.TextView.png"
display(Image(cropped_image))

PROJECT_ID = '6111116488'
MODEL_NAME = 'vgg_16'
VERSION_NAME ='v1'
def explicit():
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'D://setup//Development//sfsfc1111.json')

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)

def call_ml_service(img_str):
    parent = 'projects/{}/models/{}/versions/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_NAME,VERSION_NAME)
    pred = None
    request_dict = {
        "instances": [
            {
                "image": {
                    "b64": "%s"%img_str
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    try:
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('D://setup//Development//sfsfc1111.json')
        #credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        cloudml_svc = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
        request = cloudml_svc.projects().predict(name=parent, body=request_dict)
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
        #pred = response['predictions'][0]['scores']
        #pred = numpy.asarray(pred)
    except:
        logging.exception("Something went wrong!")
    return pred

# base64 encode the same image
with open(cropped_image, 'rb') as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
#print(encoded_string)
explicit()
# See what ML Engine thinks
online_prediction = call_ml_service(encoded_string)
print(online_prediction)
```

But, 403 "Access to model denied." was occurred.
error codes:

```
(tensorflow1.14) D:\work\models\research\slim>python inference_google_aiplatform.py
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
[<Bucket: android-ios-new-vcm>]
ERROR:root:Something went wrong!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inference_google_aiplatform.py", line 48, in call_ml_service
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1.14\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1.14\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/6111116488/models/vgg_16/versions/v1:predict?alt=json returned "Access to model denied.">
None
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you try giving the SA as a test the role of project Admin, if it's still not able to access the model, the issue si not on the roles, and we cant go from there, but it will be a starting point